# Application got stuck with CPU usage up to 100%

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, cfrunloop

My application stuck with `CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION`.
In my application, I called an C function which is async. I show an waiting msg during the execution.
 When this function is terminated, it calls a delegate to close that waiting msg and show in same time an AlertView.

I use gcd to show the alertview

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.service.waitingmessage", nil), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *anAlert = ...
            [anAlert show];
             });
        });
```

Here is the screenshot of the Debugger XCode when application got stuck.
I see also that the CPU usage of my application is up to 100%, maybe that why the application is suspended by the system.

[image]

Comment: I'm not following exactly what you're trying to run in the background.  You're creating a background queue and immediately stuffing it with a main loop block.  You could delete the first and last line and obtain the same effect.  Also note that `UIAlertView` is deprecated and you'll get any kind of block-wise handling y using a `UIAlertController`.

Comment: I've fixed the problem. This is caused by another block of code. PS: The UIAlertView is only obsoleted from iOS 8.0

Answer (score -1):

Use `dispatch_sync()` in place of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...`

You can't update the UI from a background thread.

Comment: But in my dispatch_async, I add the code to be executed in the main queue. I think that it's correct to update the UI like that.

Comment: You should't execute too your async on main queue. The best practice is to create a background queue to use it with dispatch_async() and use dispatch_get_main_queue() for your dispatch_sync() calls.